# Async not working in ForEach function and for...of is not recognizing the values

Tags: javascript, mongodb, discord.js

I am currently working on a discord bot that tracks the moderators activity in handing out roles. I did this in an event file, which writes into the db. Now I want to read the Data of all the mods. Where can I implement the async in the forEach loop that my await works?

```
let mods = message.guild.roles.cache.get(data.guild.modrole).members

let embed = new MessageEmbed()

mods.forEach( m => {
    let modData = await data.members.findOrCreate({id: m.user.id, gID: message.guild.id})
    let uTag = message.guild.members.cache.get(m.user.id).user.tag

    embed.addField(uTag, modData, true)
        })
```

I tried using a for...of loop, which didn't work because the values weren't recognized what makes no sense for me.

```
let mods = message.guild.roles.cache.get(data.guild.modrole).members

let embed = new MessageEmbed()

    for (let m of mods) {

        let modData = await data.members.findOrCreate({id: m.user.id, gID: message.guild.id})
        let uTag = message.guild.members.cache.get(m.user.id).user.tag

        embed.addField(uTag, modData, true)

    }
```

But for me, none of these worked, is there any way I can solve this problem? Thank you for your answer and kind regards,
Knirpsii

Comment: Is there an error you can provide?

Comment: well, if I use the for...of, there is a typeError because he can't read the property of the variable m, but this is only with the for...of loop.

Answer (score 0):

the second example (for ... of ) should have worked. make sure the enveloping function has async.

example :

```
async function myFunc ()  {
let mods = message.guild.roles.cache.get(data.guild.modrole).members

let embed = new MessageEmbed()

    for (let m of mods) {

        let modData = await data.members.findOrCreate({id: m.user.id, gID: message.guild.id})
        let uTag = message.guild.members.cache.get(m.user.id).user.tag

        embed.addField(uTag, modData, true)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

add async in the forEach :

```js
mods.forEach(async m => {
    let modData = await data.members.findOrCreate({id: m.user.id, gID: message.guild.id})
    let uTag = message.guild.members.cache.get(m.user.id).user.tag

    embed.addField(uTag, modData, true)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to avoid using `forEach` while using `async/await`

as `forEach` is not promise-aware, so it will not handle your await promise in the way you want

by the way the `for-of` loop should work, just make sure to add the `async` keyword to the function that contain all this part of code